# How can I configure Packetbeat to prevent sending preflight http requst( OPTIONS request)

Tags: elasticsearch, packetbeat

how can i know http method
How can I configure Packetbeat to prevent sending preflight http requst( OPTIONS request)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can't filter on method in HTTP module of Packetbeat, if you use Logstash pipeline, try to drop OPTIONS in Logstash

Comment: I am new in Logstash,  how can I drop OPTIONS in Logstash

Comment: See logstash filter `mutate`

Comment: do u have an idea, how to get http method (post get ,..OPTIONS ) inside logstash